# Google Mail How to Receive New Email Notifications

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on a webapp and want it to trigger when my users get a new email in their inbox. The one solution I have right now is to have them set up a forwarding rule to a special email we create for them (trigger-abc123@mycompany.com) and monitor that inbox normally.

However, I would like to instead set up a gmail webhook of some kind so they can easily set it up with google oauth. Is there a way to do this without needing to get approval for restricted gmail scopes?

I tried reading the google API docs for the pub/sub docs (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) however nothing here talks about the required scopes I would need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no workaround. If you want to directly access end-user Gmail inboxes your app will have to undergo a security assessment which will likely require an annual assessment fee (which could run you thousands of dollars).